# How to parallelise nested loop in my case

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have simplified my python code as:

```
import numpy.ma as ma

a=ma.zeros((10, 5, 5))
b=ma.zeros((10, 5, 5))
c=ma.zeros((10, 5, 5))
for i in np.arange(5):
    for j in np.arange(5):
        r =a[:,i,j]
        p =b[:,i,j]
        c[:,i,j] = r*p
```

How to parallelize the code so it can be done by, for example, 4 processors simultaneously and automatically giving correct output?

Any suggestions?

Comment: It'd probably be faster to just dump this on the GPU instead if that's an option, or use some SIMD extensions if that's viable.

Comment: Generally you'd need utils from the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library, if you want to do this by hand. Then you need to find a inteligent way to split the tasks and ensure that all value accesses are threadsave. Anything but a one-liner solution. So library for GPU or vectorised processing seems the better ideea here.